# Dependent Selection using UIPickerView on 3rd Button

Tags: swift, xcode, selection, uipickerview

I want button3 to show elements using uipickerview based on button2 selection. button3 will depend on button2.

["Round": ["X", "Y", "Z"]]

["Square": ["X", "Y", "Z"], "Oval": ["A", "B", "C"], "Rectangle": ["1", "2", "3"]]

["Triangle Cut": ["X", "Y", "Z"], "Sphere": ["A", "B", "C"]]

Here's the current xcode script:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var textField_0: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField_1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField_2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mainPicker: UIPickerView!


private var shapeOptions = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

private var shape1 = [["Round"],
    ["Square", "Oval", "Rectangle"],
    ["Triangle", "Sphere"]]

private var shape2 = [["X", "Y", "Z"],
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["1", "2", "3"]]

private var _currentSelection: Int = 0

var currentSelection: Int {
    get {
        return _currentSelection
    }
    set {
        _currentSelection = newValue
        mainPicker.reloadAllComponents()

        textField_0.text = shapeOptions[_currentSelection]
        textField_1.text = shape1[_currentSelection][0]
        textField_2.text = shape2[_currentSelection][0]
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentSelection = 0;
    }

    @IBAction func btn1Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.delegate = self
        mainPicker.dataSource = self
        mainPicker.tag = 0
        mainPicker.isHidden = false
    }

    @IBAction func btn2Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.delegate = self
        mainPicker.dataSource = self
        mainPicker.tag = 1
        mainPicker.isHidden = false
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return shapeOptions.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return shape1[currentSelection].count
        } else {
            return shape2[currentSelection].count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return shapeOptions[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return shape1[currentSelection][row]
        } else {
            return shape2[currentSelection][row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            currentSelection = row
            textField_0.text = shapeOptions[row]
            textField_0.resignFirstResponder()
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            textField_1.text = shape1[currentSelection][row]
            textField_1.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField_2.text = shape2[currentSelection][row]
            textField_2.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a little more in detail? You have three buttons that change the selection of the pickerView? What happens when I tap on button3?

Comment: @rs7 For example: BUTTON1 (Human, Animals, Plants); BUTTON2 (Human: American, European, Asian); Animals: (Dogs, Cats, Reptiles); Plants: (Fruits, Vegetables, Meat); BUTTON3 (American: Male, Female); European...; Asian...; Dogs(Wolf, Hyenas, Fox); Cats(Tigers, Lions, Cheetah); Reptiles... I hope my explanation is clear :-D or this might help [link](https://prnt.sc/t1m1j3)

Comment: So let's say first you are presented with a selection consisting of [human, animals, plants] in the pickerView. You pick human and you tap button1, then the pickerView selection changes to [American, European, Asian]. You pick European and tap button2, now the selection changes to [Male, Female]. Finally, you use button 3 to make the last selection. Am I understanding this right? If yes, why do you need 3 different buttons? Do they appear one after the other?

Comment: @rs7 when you click Button1 pickerview will show [human, animals, plants], then when you click Button2 pickerview will show [American, European, Asian], then when you click Button3 pickerview will show [Male, Female]... each button has its own label that's why its needed. in my script, Button1 and Button2 is doing okay, but not on Button3.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

- Button3 function is missing from your code.
- You don't need to set the pickerview delegate/datasource each time you click on a button.
- If I understand what you want correctly, you don't need to unhide the pickerView each time you press a button. Just unhide it when you press the first button.
- I'm not sure what the textFields do, but consider moving the textField code inside the buttons functions.
- I modified your code below. You only want to reload the pickerView when a button is tapped to confirm selection. What you were doing in your code was reloading the pickerView every time the user changed the picker selection.
- (optional) Instead of using tags, you could have a pickerViewIndex variable with a didSet block that would reload the pickerView. And inside the functions, instead of assigning a value to the pickerView.tag, you would assign a value to the pickerViewIndex.

```
    var currentSelection: Int {
    get {
        return _currentSelection
    }
    set {
        _currentSelection = newValue
        // Consider moving the code below to the buttons functions
        textField_0.text = shapeOptions[_currentSelection]
        textField_1.text = shape1[_currentSelection][0]
        textField_2.text = shape2[_currentSelection][0]
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentSelection = 0;

        mainPicker.delegate = self
        mainPicker.dataSource = self

    }

    @IBAction func btn1Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.tag = 0
        mainPicker.isHidden = false
        mainPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }

    @IBAction func btn2Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.tag = 1
        mainPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }

    @IBAction func btn3Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.tag = 2
        mainPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return shapeOptions.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return shape1[currentSelection].count
        } else {
            return shape2[currentSelection].count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return shapeOptions[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return shape1[currentSelection][row]
        } else {
            return shape2[currentSelection][row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            currentSelection = row
            textField_0.text = shapeOptions[row]
            textField_0.resignFirstResponder()
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            currentSelection = row
            textField_1.text = shape1[currentSelection][row]
            textField_1.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            currentSelection = row
            textField_2.text = shape2[currentSelection][row]
            textField_2.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```

Comment: first of all, I would like to thank you for spending time to do the codes. I appreciate it. But the button3 part is not yet met. [Option1 : "Round": ["X", "Y", "Z"]]

[Option 2: "Square": ["X", "Y", "Z"], "Oval": ["A", "B", "C"], "Rectangle": ["1", "2", "3"]]

[Option 3: "Triangle Cut": ["X", "Y", "Z"], "Sphere": ["A", "B", "C"]]

Comment: I didn't set the appropriate tag. I updated my answer. You need to change the first line of the button 3 function from mainPicker.tag = 1 to mainPicker.tag = 2 and that should do it.

Comment: I posted the answer. Thank you for all your response. I appreciate it. Now, the next help I need is getting the value from a CSV File in columns, based from the selection.

Answer (score 0):

@rs7 I was able to get an answer from someone, this is the answer I was looking for:

```
private var shapeOptions = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

private var shape = [["Round"],
    ["Square", "Oval", "Rectangle"],
    ["Triangle", "Sphere"]]

private var sizeA:[[String]] = [["X", "Y", "Z"]]
private var sizeB:[[String]] = [["A", "B", "C"]]
private var sizeC:[[String]] = [["1", "2", "3"]]

    private var sizes:[[[String]]]?
 

    var currentTypeSelection: Int? {
        didSet{
            mainPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

    var currentSizeSelection: Int? {
        didSet{
            mainPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sizes = [sizeA, sizeB, sizeC]

        currentTypeSelection = 0;
        currentSizeSelection = 0;
    }
    
    @IBAction func btn1Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.delegate = self
        mainPicker.dataSource = self
        mainPicker.tag = 0
        mainPicker.isHidden = false
    }
    
    @IBAction func btn2Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.delegate = self
        mainPicker.dataSource = self
        mainPicker.tag = 1
        mainPicker.isHidden = false
    }
    
    @IBAction func btn3Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        mainPicker.delegate = self
        mainPicker.dataSource = self
        mainPicker.tag = 2
        mainPicker.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return shapeOptions.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return shape[currentTypeSelection!].count
        } else {
            return sizes![currentTypeSelection!][currentSizeSelection!].count
        } 
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return shapeOptions[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return shape[currentTypeSelection!][row]
        } else {
            return sizes![currentTypeSelection!][currentSizeSelection!][row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            currentTypeSelection = row
            textField_0.text = shapeOptions[row]
            textField_0.resignFirstResponder()
            currentSizeSelection = 0
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            currentSizeSelection = row
            textField_1.text = shape[currentTypeSelection!][row]
            textField_1.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField_2.text = sizes![currentTypeSelection!][currentSizeSelection!][row]
            textField_2.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```